# SpringMVC built by IDEA: No converter found for return value of type

Tags: java, spring

I use IDEA to build a simple RESTful server based on SpringMVC. But @RestController and @ResponseBody can't convert POJO to JSON by jackson JSON.

In **dispatcher-servlet.xml**:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

In **pom.xml**:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

My controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/one")
    public One getOne() {
        return new One(1);
    }
}
```

My POJO:

```
public class One {
    public One(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    private int number;
```

}

But I still get the **No converter found for return value of type** error.
I don't know why. Have I met some config or something else?

Comment: I solve this problem in this way:

project-structures -> artifacts -> add jacksonXXX.jar to output root .....

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
     <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
   </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Comment: I tried this but got new error:
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/DefaultPrettyPrinter$Indenter
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)

Comment: I have solved  this problem. i forgot to add jars to artifacts.... Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify produces/consumes to define which type of data type you want, for example:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/one")
    public One getOne() {
        return new One(1);
    }
}
```